# Qualified name of class in Quick Fix dialog to do static imports

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using both Mockito and Hamcrest in my Eclipse project. When I want to use Quick Fix to do static import, I cannot see qualified name of class in Quick Fix dialog and I usually choose the wrong class. How can I solve it? Is there a configuration option to show fully qualified names?

[image]

Comment: Do you have configured static imports? Window -> Preferences -> Editor -> Favorites ? Like org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*, org.mockito.Matcher.* . If yes then you should also had a yellow-window with description of fully qualified name.